# How to Move The Google Logo and Move the Zoom Buttons in Xamarin Froms Maps in a Cross Platform App?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

In the code that I wrote a portion of the screen is covered by a semi-transparent control center on top of a map intentionally. In order to have a more presentable visual in my app I want to move the Google logo relatively to on top of the control center and remove the zoom buttons without disabling the zoom property on the map.
My .xaml code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:map="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:pan ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="GreenPath.MainPage">

    <Grid>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <map:Map MapType="Street" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <yummy:PancakeView CornerRadius="25,25,0,0" Opacity="0.8" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" TranslationY="550">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                <Image Source="down.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1"/>
                <Label  Text="X" TextColor="#3E454F" FontSize="40" FontFamily="segoeui.ttf" Margin="10,0"/>
                <SearchBar FontFamily="segoeui.ttf" Text="X" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalOptions="Fill" SearchButtonPressed="SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed" PlaceholderColor="#3E454F" TextColor="#3E454F" CancelButtonColor="#3E454F" Visual="Material" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="Search a location" IsEnabled="True"/>
                <Label Text="X" FontFamily="segoeui.ttf" FontSize="25" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#3E454F" Margin="10,0"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" ColumnSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="3" />
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="4" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </yummy:PancakeView>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can but definitely you shouldn't as this is part of the Google Requirements and doing so will break the "Terms of Services":

(b) Attribution. Customer will display all attribution that (i) Google provides through the Services (including branding, logos, and copyright and trademark notices); or (ii) is specified in the Maps Service Specific Terms. Customer will not modify, obscure, or delete such attribution.

More information can be seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/?csw=1#9-license-requirements):

Comment: I don’t want to remove Google logo I want to move it because it gets covered.

Answer (score 0):

For zoom controls:

In your `xaml`, name your map ex. `x:Name="map"`.

In your `xaml.cs`, do `map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;`

For the Google Logo:

I don't believe you can hide this.

Edit: i misread your question and thought for some reason you were using [Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps). That is what my answer is for, but i'll leave it here in case someone else makes the same mistake and stumbles here.